# Pandas - compare column ID in rows and delete conditionally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

In an example dataframe like:

```
Qid     Sid     L1  L2
id01    id02    74  72
id01    id03    74  68
id02    id01    72  74
id02    id03    72  68
```

I'd like to delete the reciprocal hit, so the output should be:

```
Qid     Sid     L1  L2
id01    id02    74  72
id01    id03    74  68
id02    id03    72  68
```

In my real dataset I have thousands of lines, the above is just to explain the idea.

Comment: use `np.sort` with `axis=1` on the two columns `Qid, Sid` and drop duplicates

Comment: may be he also checks L1 and L2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another idea:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = {'Qid':['id01','id01','id02','id02'],'Sid':['id02','id02','id01','id03'],'L1':[74,74,72,72],'L2':[72,68,74,68]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df[['L1','L2']] = df[['L1','L2']].astype(str) #Turn the values into strings so you can create sortable list over it.
df['aux'] = df[['Qid','Sid','L1','L2']].values.tolist() #create a list of the 4 columns
df['aux'] = df['aux'].apply(sorted).astype(str) #sort the list and treat it as a full string.
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='aux').drop(columns='aux') #drop the rows where the list is duplicate, that is, there is the same combination of Qid, Sid, L1 and L2.
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    Qid   Sid  L1  L2
0  id01  id02  74  72
1  id01  id02  74  68
3  id02  id03  72  68
```